# AJAX call and Laravel 5.4 controller balance

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a controller like this -

```
public function imagedelete($id) {
$image = imagesforpeople::find($id);
        $image->delete();
        return back();
        }
```

In this controller, I am calling return back() which refreshes the page upon deleting that image. I just don't want to refresh the page but I want to stay at the same page but the image will be deleted, and it's updated in real time. So, I want to call ajax, something like this in my controller

```
public function imagedelete($id) {
$image = imagesforpeople::find($id);
        $image->delete();
        call ajax view();
        }
```

My route is like this

```
Route::delete('/profile/people/image/{id}','Profilepagecontroller@imagedelete');
```

How do I construct my ajax call for this route?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url : "/profile/people/image/{id}",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
             }
          });
```

Any help would be reallly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Change your route like this

```
Route::post('delete-photo', 'Profilepagecontroller@imagedelete')->name('deletephoto');
```

The change your controller function

```
public function imagedelete(Request $request) {
        $id=$request->image_id;
        $image = imagesforpeople::find($id);
        $image->delete();
        $data['success']=true;
        return response()->json($data);
        }
```

Your ajax code will be like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : '{{route('deletephoto')}}',
            data: {
              image_id: '{id}' ,
              _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'                         
                    },
     success : function (data) {
     if (data.success == true) {
            console.log('image deleted');
                  }}
              }); });
```

Comment: Using GET request for deleting an image?

Comment: i have modified code for post request check it out.